# Understanding sub-sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Well, i currently studying about sequence and sub sequence and i noticed that i have problem with the definition. $$A\:subsequence\:of\:\left\{a\right\}\:is\:a\:sequence\:\left\{b\right\}\:defined\:by\:b_k=a_{\left(n_k\right)},\:where\:n_1<n_2<...\:is\:an\:increasing\:sequence\:of\:indices$$.

Now, for understanding, if for example $a_n\:=\:\frac{1}{n}$, what the meaning of
 expressions " $a_{n-1}\:,\:a_{2n}\:,\:a_{2n-1}$" ? can someone explain me? tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sequence $a_n$. Suppose you've listed the terms $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6...$. To get subsequence $b_n$ you underline the terms of $a_n$ which you like. Suppose you underlined first, third, fifth... all odd numbered terms. Then you throw away all terms that you didn't underline. You get $b_k=(a_1,a_3,a_5,a_7...)$. More clearly you can define $b_k=a_{n_k}=a_{2k-1}$ since $n_k=2k-1$ cause you take only odd numbered indexes. But notice that $n_k$ has to be an increasing sequence, since after you have thrown the even terms you can't mix the left ones. You just count the new sequence again starting from 1 so you have $b_1=a_1, b_2=a_3,b_3=a_5,...,b_k=a_{2k-1},...$

Comment: tnx a lot. you can explain me this : $a_{n-1}$ ? now $n_k\:=\:k-1$?  what does it mean?

Comment: $b_k=a_{n_k}=a_{k-1}$.
So $b_1=a_{1-1}=a_0$, $b_2=a_1$,...,$b_k=a_k-1$.
I'm afraid that you can't define subsequence for $n_k=k-1$ since any sequence starts from first term, not "zeroth". So your $b_1$ is undefined since there is no $a_0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\;a_{n-1}=\frac1{n-1}\;,\;\;n\neq 1\;,\;\;a_{2n}=\frac1{2n}\;,\;\;a_{2n-1}=\frac1{2n-1}$$

If you take each subsequence defined by the above general terms, you get: the original sequence (but beginning with $\;n=2\;$ instead), the subsequence of even indexes, and the subsequence of odd indexes, resp.